# Could we get the audio embedding feature for PPCG?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

[Music and AVP](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97610/201409) and [Signal Processing](https://dsp.meta.stackexchange.com/q/83/11608) can embed audio files via the SoundCloud player. Since the feature already exists, it would only need to be activated for PPCG, and judging by Signal Processing the devs will actually do so if there's some support in the community for it.

**Why I think this would be useful:** We've had a handful of [audio](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/audio) challenges, and I'm sure we'll have more in the future. But in general these are not as popular as [graphical-output](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-output) or [image-processing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/image-processing). Part of that might be people being less familiar with audio than graphics, but I think a major problem with audio challenges is that you currently cannot easily listen to the results, like you can look at the pictures produced in graphical challenges. I think that's quite a barrier for these challenges, and we could do a lot more interesting audio-based challenges if we could embed the results right in the answers.

So please indicate your opinion by voting the question up or down, and leave a comment or an answer if you want to add something. And if this gets some support, I'll ping a mod to ask the devs if they could activate this.

Comment: +1 I can't think of any reason to avoid this. When proposing MathJax for a site there's usually some mention of slightly slower page load times and unreadable posts while rendering is in progress. Does anyone know of any analogous drawback with introducing audio embedding?

Comment: @trichoplax I talked to balpha last week and asked him about this, and he said these problems don't occur for the soundcloud embedding because a) it's all done server-side and b) no additional JavaScript or similar has to be dished out for all pages (only those which actually contain an embedded audio file).

Comment: Just so people know, to embed a SoundCloud track you just need to paste the plain SoundCloud link (e.g. [https://soundcloud.com/deoncustom/zelda-song-of-storms-deon-custom-remix](https://soundcloud.com/deoncustom/zelda-song-of-storms-deon-custom-remix)) in your Markdown wherever you want it to be. It won't render in the post preview but it will become the Flash box when posted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Testing whether this works on Code Golf:

Comment: This post doesn't seem to be working in Google Chrome due to it using a non-`https://` URL

Answer (score 11):

Note that uploading to SoundCloud will result in the file being [transcoded to 128kbps mp3](http://help.soundcloud.com/customer/portal/articles/94796-just-uploaded-and-my-track-is-distorted), which could have undesirable effects in some cases. So if this feature is enabled, people should choose to make their file downloadable.