# Does Code Golf support embedded YouTube videos?

Tags: support, formatting

Over on Meta Stack Exchange, SQB asked *[Which sites have YouTube embedding on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297500/351462)*

Searching on Meta Code Golf, I was able to find an [announcement post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3616/could-we-get-the-audio-embedding-feature-for-ppcg) for embedded SoundCloud audio files, but found no mention of embedded YouTube videos. Additionally, [YouTube embedding is not shown in the markdown preview window](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/299082/351462), so there's no way to test without posting publically.

I originally planned on testing in the *[Sandbox for Proposed Challenges](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges)* before [Noah Cristino recommended I ask here on Meta](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39036487#39036487).

**Are embedded YouTube videos supported on Code Golf?**

Comment: *Please* let the answer be **no**.

Comment: @Dennis You can breathe a sigh of relief.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's only one way to find out.

## Testing YouTube URL Embedding

**Regular** `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8`

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8

---

**Timestamped** `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8&t=22`

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8&t=22

---

**Shortened** `https://youtu.be/gocwRvLhDf8`

https://youtu.be/gocwRvLhDf8

---

**/Embed** `https://www.youtube.com/embed/gocwRvLhDf8`

https://www.youtube.com/embed/gocwRvLhDf8

---

**Embedded HTML** `<iframe width="854" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/gocwRvLhDf8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

---

**Mobile** `https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8`

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=gocwRvLhDf8

---

**Flash Player** `https://www.youtube.com/v/gocwRvLhDf8`

https://www.youtube.com/v/gocwRvLhDf8

---

**YouTube TV** `https://www.youtube.com/tv#/watch/video/idle?v=gocwRvLhDf8`

https://www.youtube.com/tv#/watch/video/idle?v=gocwRvLhDf8

---

<sub>See [*Which sites have YouTube embedding on?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298854/351462)</sub>